# Sending text to windows clipboard with iOS shortcuts

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-11, clipboard, ios

The command interacting with the clipboard:

```
echo <text> | clip
```

In the ios shortcut app, i try to do this remotely with the "run script over ssh" command block, but nothing is appended to the windows clipboard when the shortcut script is ran

The echo clip command works on a local cmd console

The same command on localhost SSH also works

can be sure that the ssh connection is up and the ssh ios shortcut works with some other command

The windows version is Win11 pro 23H2

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the clipboard inside the SSH session and would like it to be available in the server?

Comment: The clipboard should be put on the server clipboard as in the list view shown by Win+V. By clipboard ssh section, do you mean there’s a separate clipboard with ssh? If it is then it might be what I’m missing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a basic misunderstanding here :
The clipboard is different for each user session, each has got his own,
and sessions are isolated to prevent data leak.

This means that the desktop login session uses a different clipboard
than that of the SSH login session, and that one cannot access the other.

Sharing data needs to be done via mechanisms such as a shared file,
database or a note-taking application.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this, but ssh clip works on localhost connection. It just doesn’t work when I do the same through shortcuts. Do you mean ssh on localhost is a different section from ssh-ing in shortcuts?

Comment: Connecting from a session to itself is different.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).